# Dell r710 idrac6 is not visible/reachable on network

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac, server-setup

I got a (new) r710 server, and tried setting up idrac6, i reset to default and changed the ipv4 settings to an ip in my network, i also tried dhcp, i set up a root password, and still there will be no idrac on my network, no web interface, and even pinging the ip does not work, does anybody know something i could have missed?

Comment: contact the vendor support that you hopefully bought. it's faster special while using nbd support from dell

Comment: If there‘s a dedicated iDRAC port make sure it‘s connected to the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required note: I work for Dell

Regarding @djdomi’s comment; there is no vendor support for the R710 and there’s no way this was bought new… at least not from Dell. The R710 was released in 2009 . Suffice it to say it’s more than a little EOL.

@Zac67 is right, this is more than likely some sort of network issue.

There should be a dedicated iDRAC port - make sure it is plugged in and then give it a ping.

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I know that the server isn't new, but it's a new device for me. The dedicated IDrac port is connected to the same switch as many other ports, and all other devices work on that switch. So there should be no network issue, I set the IDrac networking mode to dedicated and set up static ip v4 and it won't work. I also tried DHCP

Comment: tbh, that's really the only possibility aside from you have a bad iDRAC card. That server is older than dirt so that's not impossible, but if you're seeing link lights it's not my first thought. Try plugging the server directly into something else, put that something else on the same subnet, and see if it works when they're directly connected. That narrows down the problem set for you pretty fast, but with this problem it can really only be one of two things. Bad card, bad network config. If there are link lights, my money is on network config problem.